# nginx reverse proxy IIS

Tags: nginx, iis

When I try to enter < z://www.aaacom/iis2002 >, it turned to my net core IIS site < z://www.aaa.com:2002 >, but the jump page, Turned into < z://www.aaa.com/index.html > not < z://www.aaa.com:2002/index.html >, I want is my net core alter what iis site needs to cooperate? Or is my nginx configuration itself wrong?

[image]
` server {
listen       443 ssl;
server_name  www.aaa.com;

```
    ssl_certificate      sslkey/71_www.aaa.com.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  sslkey/71_www.aaa.com.key;

    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    location / {         
        proxy_pass z://127.0.0.1:4430;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }

   
    location = / {          
        proxy_pass z://127.0.0.1:4430/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
    

location /iis2002 {     
        proxy_pass z://www.aaa.com:2002;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }           

    
    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
}`
```

Correct jump to <z://www.aaa.com:2002>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add the host port in your configuration and check if this work for you:

```
proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
```